# QGraphicsView connect a line to another QGraphicsSceneItem

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm extending Qt's QGraphicsView framework to create an interactive shape builder. When you click and drag, it creates a control point with a bezier handle to effect its curve (same as paths in let's say, Photoshop).

I have separate items for the control point, and both bezier handle points. I'm struggling with a way to display the bezier handle's line segment, that goes from a bezier point to the control point.

Example of the straight bezier line on top:
[image: Want to create that line!]

What's the best approach to display that? I tried to override the paintEvent, which draws the line just fine, but some parts of the view didn't clear and it gets a bit funky.

Here's what the code looked like:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):

    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.viewport())

    if self.points:
        painter.begin(self)
        painter.fillRect(self.viewport().rect(), QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(50, 50, 50)))
        for point in self.points:
            if point.point_type != ControlPoint.Bezier:
                continue

            painter.drawLine(point.handle_1.pos().x(), point.handle_1.pos().y(), 
                             point.handle_2.pos().x(), point.handle_2.pos().y());
        painter.end()

    QtGui.QGraphicsView.paintEvent(self, event)
```

Or is a better approach to create an item for the line itself? Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution so far. I'm sub-classing `QGraphicsScene.drawForeground` to draw all the lines between any bezier points. The only bad thing is that I have to update the whole viewport otherwise it doesn't clear all previous draws. So this may shoot me in the foot later performance-wise.

Other than that, it works perfect, even when moving the points around, I get a nice segment that's following.

```
def drawForeground(self, painter, rect):
    view = self.views()[0]

    # Forces whole view to update instead of partial.
    view.viewport().update()

    painter.begin(view)

    if view.points:
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.white, 1, QtCore.Qt.DashLine)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        for point in view.points:
            if point.point_type != ControlPoint.Bezier:
                continue

            painter.drawLine(point.handle_1.pos().x(), point.handle_1.pos().y(), 
                             point.handle_2.pos().x(), point.handle_2.pos().y());
    painter.end()

    return QtGui.QGraphicsScene.drawBackground(self, painter, rect)
```